# Python - How to prevent MySQLdb cursor update interfering with fetchmany?

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    def result_generator(cursor, batch_size=10):
        while True:
            results = cursor.fetchmany(batch_size)
            if not results:
                break
            for res in results:
                yield res

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="domains")
    # you must create a Cursor object. It will let
    #  you execute all the queries you need
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT domain FROM com ORDER BY id ASC")
    for result in result_generator(cursor):
        url = "http://www.{0}".format(result[0])
        print url
        w = Wappalyzer(url)
        out = w.analyze()
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE com SET frameworks=%s, is_checked=1 WHERE domain=%s""",
                       (db.escape_string(out.get('frameworks', "")), result[0]))
    # disconnect from server
    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

My current code runs only for the first 10 rows.

Since i'm using `fetchmany` function, its supposed to run continuously by selecting the next 10 rows until the end.

But the `cursor.execute("""UPDATE ....` interfere with the fetchmany `cursor.execute("SELECT ...` .

Can someone tell me what is the proper way to prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried using a different cursor (don't mix the one doing the selecting with the one doing the update).

Comment: @metatoaster Yes I tried that. But i'm getting mysql errors like `InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of executing the UPDATE queries directly, put them in a string and run them all at once after you're done iterating through the results of the SELECT query

Comment: Hi there, I'm querying around 100 million rows. Do you think the server will hold 100 million rows in memory as string?

Comment: @Giri The only number you mentioned in your question is 10. I can't blame him.

Comment: you can easily wrap it in a loop for batched processing

Comment: @aIKid Yep forgot to mention that. I thought you guys knew i'm dealing with large rows when i use fetchmany function

Comment: ...or write the domains from SELECT in a file before proceeding with UPDATE

Comment: @Pavel I don't think writing it into a file and then reading from there will be the right way of doing it. But thanks for your answer

Comment: and you are sure you can't afford keeping all domains in memory? if a domain name is ~50 bytes, it'll take about 5G RAM, which doesn't sound too bad for a server.

Comment: @Pavel You've got a point.. It's just sounds like a lot, 100 million.

Comment: @aIKid Do you guys have any idea how bad i'm gonna look like as a programmer, if i'm going to waste 5GB RAM for storing domain names just like a physical storage?. Python has been around since the early 1990s. So i'm pretty sure MySQLdb module has an easy solution for that. I would rather try with different cursors than loading the whole database in my RAM or writing in a file and then trying them.

Comment: If you haven't found the solution, then you have wasted three hours. The meaning of 'efficient' needs to be questioned again.